# Swagger não exibe métodos que contenham parâmetros do tipo array

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Criei uma `WebApi`com métodos básicos com o intuito de usar o `Swagger`. Observei que métodos que possuem parâmetros simples como o ilustrado no código abaixo são exibidos pelo `Swagger` porém métodos que possuem algum vetor, este é suprimido. Tentei alterar o `SwaggerConfig.cs` definindo um `MapType` da seguinte forma `c.MapType<string[]>(() => new Schema { type = "string[]", format = "string[]" });`porém sem sucesso. No arquivo de configuração do projeto a opção `XML documentation file` existente dentro da aba `Build` está selecionada o que está gerando o arquivo XML de documentação.

**Método listado no Swagger**

```
    // GET: api/Default
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

**Método que não é listado no Swagger**

```
    // GET: api/Get/paramstring
    public IEnumerable<string> GetArray(string[] paramstring)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Versão do Swagger 8.3.44.1;

Versão do .Net 4.6.1

Comment: De uma olhada aqui
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281532/specify-an-array-of-strings-as-body-parameter-in-swagger-api

Comment: De onde você tirou essa versão do Swagger?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/